# How can I run FIO for windows and redirect output to file and console simultaneously

Tags: console-redirect

I’m running FIO 2.1.8 (Windows 2012 R2) and I am trying to figure out how I can use a bat file with FIO and the **–output=** command, but also display the output to the console screen at the same time.

I want to be able to monitor the screen in real time but also need a log so I can parse for errors and metrics after the workload is done. The problem is it seems there is no way to do both.

If I include the output argument then all screen output is suppressed, and if I try to do any other type of redirection then the console never updates.

Does anyone know how to achieve this with FIO in Windows?

I've tried using

- TEE (via Gow)
- Standard dos redirection   (eg &>1 )
- Wrapping the bat file in a powershell script using START-TRANSCRIPT

In all cases this does not work.

```
"C:\Program Files\fio\fio.exe" --name=warmup --readwrite=randrw --rwmixread=70 --bs=64k --ba=64k --filename=E\:\FIO_
datafile.dat --size=32m --ioengine=windowsaio  --runtime=900 --time_based --iodepth=4 --numjobs=32  --eta=always
```

Thanks...

Comment: If you can change the source, you could consider sending the output to a socket to a localhost port. And listen with another app on that port...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell's Tee-Object worked for me:

```
& ./fio --eta=always --ioengine=null --thread --time_based --runtime=10s --size=1M --name=go | Tee-Object fioout.txt
```

(An aside: due to the way Windows works you don't exactly have pseudo-ttys so it's often hard for other programs to pretend to be terminals in a way the originating program won't detect as being a redirection to a file)